# How to replace while True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am working on 706. Design HashMap Leetcode question. There is while True loop which I have a hard time writing it. I tried to rewriting it to while cur.next is not None, but it didn't work as expected. Is it possible to change it?

706. Design HashMap

Design a HashMap without using any built-in hash table libraries.

To be specific, your design should include these functions:

put(key, value) : Insert a (key, value) pair into the HashMap. If the value already exists in the HashMap, update the value.

get(key): Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or -1 if this map contains no mapping for the key.

remove(key) : Remove the mapping for the value key if this map contains the mapping for the key.

```
def __init__(self):
    """
    Initialize your data structure here.
    """


def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
    """
    value will always be non-negative.
    """


def get(self, key: int) -> int:
    """
    Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or -1 if this map contains no mapping for the key
    """


def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
    """
    Removes the mapping of the specified value key if this map contains a mapping for the key
    """



cur = self.h[index]
while True:
    if cur.pair[0] == key:
        cur.pair = (key, value) #update
        return
    if cur.next == None: break
    cur = cur.next
cur.next = ListNode(key, value)



cur = self.h[index]
while cur.next is not None:
    if cur.pair[0] == key:
        cur.pair = (key, value) #update
        return
    cur = cur.next
cur.next = ListNode(key, value)
```

Comment: Can you post the basic details of the Leetcode question, as well as all of the class code that Leetcode includes?

Comment: Honestly `while True:` with a `break` inside the loop is already pretty idiomatic Python. Is there a reason you want to rewrite it?

Comment: @Weeble Is it idiomatic? Thank you. I will get used to it then.

Comment: Why not `while cur is not None`? In the last line of the loop you set `cur = cur.next`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two variables to keep track of your current and next node.  Then the while loop can be more expressive and the issue is one of initialization rather than loop structure:

```
nextNode = self.h[index]
while nextNode:
    curNode = nextNode
    if curNode.pair[0] == key:
        curNode.pair = (key, value) #update
        return
    nextNode = curNode.next
curNode.next = ListNode(key, value)
```